# Ruby on Rails - Carmen gem: undefined method `country_select' for #<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0x5a53598>

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, carmen

I'm pulling my hair out with this one.  I've tried installing the Carmen gem, then uninstalling it and trying this as a plugin, then uninstalling the plugin and re-installing the gem, restarting the server but nothing seems to help.

Doesn't matter what I do, the code can't seem to find the "country_select" method.  It always fails on this line:

```
<%= f.country_select :country_code, {priority: %w(US CA)}, prompt: 'Please select a country' %>
```

I'm using Ruby 1.9.3 
carmen v1.0.0.beta2 
carmen-rails v1.0.0.beta3

I *really* need to get this working but have no idea how to further this along.  Please help...

Comment: Have you tried it without the form reference? So: <%= country_select :someId, :country_code........ %>

Comment: Wow - thanks for that blazing fast reply.  Unfortunately, that did not seem to help:  <%=  country_select :prev_country_address, :country_code, nil, prompt: 'Please select a country' %> still gave me almost the same error msg:  undefined method `country_select' for #<#<Class:0x6255348>:0x591fd80> (Class instead of ActionView::Helper...).  I don't mind trying a 100 more things if you have any other ideas.

Answer (score 3):

I came across this with simple_form, it turns out that it depends on gem country_select, if you get this error working with simple_form then install the gem:

```
gem 'country_select'
```

Then restart your server:

```
rails s
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same. I resolved it by changing :country_code to the name of the field in my model that held the country value. For example, in my model I used country and thus I changed :country_code to :country and it worked fine.